# SQL Server 2012 Dynamic Query calling from Functions return

Tags: sql-server

I have a scalar-valued [return type nvarchar] function that returns a dynamic Query String.
Let my Function is like following …

```
CREATE FUNCTION ABC
(

)
RETURNS nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    return 'Select * from Table1'
END
```

I want to Execute it like following …

```
Select * from dbo.ABC()
```

Or

```
Select * from EXEC(dbo.ABC())
```

Is That possible in SQL Server 2012?
I have to do it without using openquery.

```
-- My Actual Function --

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[RowToColumn]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here

)
RETURNS nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PunchList nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @PunchListTOP nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @Flag INT
SET @PunchList = ''
SET @PunchListTOP = ''
DECLARE @I INT
SET @Flag = (select MAX(X) as MMAX from (select Employee_ID,Date_Of_Working, count(Date_Of_Working) as X from DataInOneRowStep3 group by Date_Of_Working ,Employee_ID ) A)
Set @I =1
WHILE (@I<= @Flag)
BEGIN
if (@PunchList = '' )
BEGIN
   Set @PunchList = 'Punch_' + CONVERT(varchar, @I)  
   Set @PunchListTOP = ' MAX(Punch_' + CONVERT(varchar, @I)  +') Punch_' + CONVERT(varchar, @I)
END
else
BEGIN
Set @PunchList = @PunchList + ',' + 'Punch_' + CONVERT(varchar, @I)     
Set @PunchListTOP =@PunchListTOP +','+ ' MAX(Punch_' + CONVERT(varchar, @I)  +') Punch_' + CONVERT(varchar, @I)
END
SET @I = @I + 1
END

SET @SQL ='SELECT Employee_Id,Date_OF_Working,Shift_Id,'+@PunchListTOP+' FROM (
    SELECT * from DataInOneRowStep4 
) as s
PIVOT
(
    MAX(EntryTime)
    FOR Punch IN ('+@PunchList+')
)AS piv group by  Employee_Id,Date_OF_Working,Shift_Id'


RETURN @SQL

END
```

Comment: You cannot return NVARCHAR(MAX) datatype in a user defined functions.

Comment: ...plus the very fact you want to do the above, leads me to suspect you are doing something wrong...

Comment: Time to learn about table valued user functions.  Start here (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: OK ... I am sorry I can not understand. Why I Cannot return NVARCHAR(MAX) ? I have done already and 
The code works fine with  Select dbo.ABC()

Comment: table valued user functions do not allows do not allow Declaring variables. Multi -Statement Table valued function has fixed column. So I am not using them. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: something wrong :/ What ??@MitchWheat

Comment: also you cannot use dynamic sql inside a udf

Comment: Can you explain in detail what you want to achieve. I mean what type of output you want to achieve with the help of dummy data. It is difficult to imagine your scenario in this case.

Comment: Its seems like you want to transpose the data with help of functions.If that's the case then you should use inline table value functions or multi - statement table value functions. In you above scenario you are using scaler function which does not allow transpose .